# Android. Как добавить элементы в ListView из BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, listview, broadcast-receiver

делаю так

```
public class AddNewRequestActivity extends Activity {
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// создаем BroadcastReceiver
        br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            // действия при получении сообщений
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
String[] names = { "Иван", "Марья", "Петр", "Антон", "Даша", "Борис",
            "Костя", "Игорь", "Анна", "Денис", "Андрей" };

// находим список
                        ListView lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewRequests);
                        // создаем адаптер
                        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(AddNewRequestActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);
                        // присваиваем адаптер списку
                        lvMain.setAdapter(adapter);

  }
        };

// создаем фильтр для BroadcastReceiver
        IntentFilter intFilt = new IntentFilter(BROADCAST_ACTION);
        // регистрируем (включаем) BroadcastReceiver
        registerReceiver(br, intFilt);
    }
    }
```

в ListView не добавляются элементы(сам ListView помещается в одну из вкладок TabHost). как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вынесите объявление в `onCreate`, а в `BroadcastReceiver` только меняйте. Примерно так:

```
public class AddNewRequestActivity extends Activity {
    ListView lvMain;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    String[] names = {"Денис", "Андрей"}; //допустим, какие-то начальные данные
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewRequests);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(AddNewRequestActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);
        lvMain.setAdapter(adapter);
        br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
               String[] newNames = { "Иван", "Марья", "Петр", "Антон", "Даша", "Борис", "Костя", "Игорь", "Анна", "Денис", "Андрей" };
               adapter.clear();
               adapter.addAll(newNames);
               adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
        IntentFilter intFilt = new IntentFilter(BROADCAST_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(br, intFilt);
    }
}
```